# Iterating a hash by comparing it with two separate arrays and arrive with a new hash desired result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

1. Array 1 = 7 elements
2. Array 2 = 7 elements
3. Hash = 7 elements

My requirement is to iterate through the each element in the hash with each element in array 1 and array 2 and come out with a new hash after applying the desired logic. The comparison is always going to be between the first element in hash against first element in array 1 and first element in array 2 and so on and so forth till I complete the list.

I am not even sure where and how to start so any help is appreciated to get me started

Comment: You really need to show some example for hash1, array1 and array2.

Comment: Array 1= ['char', 'number','number','number','char','number','char']
Array 2= [6, '(7,0)','(15,0)','(5,0)',3,'(15,2)', 17]
Hash = {col1  = 123456, col2 = 0000111, col3 = 000000002345, col4 = 00023, col5 = abc, col6 = 00000000000052367, col7 = 0000000000321456}

Comment: Please update the question with an example with correct syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
arr1 = ['char', 'number', 'number', 'number', 'char', 'number', 'char']
arr2 = [6, '(7,0)','(15,0)','(5,0)',3,'(15,2)', 17]

h = { 'col1'=>'123456', 'col2'=>'0000111', 'col3'=>'000000002345',
      'col4'=>'00023',  'col5'=>'abc', 'col6'=>'00000000000052367',
      'col7'=>'0000000000321456' }
```

```
enum = arr1.zip(arr2).to_enum
  #=> #<Enumerator: [["char", 6], ["number", "(7,0)"], ["number", "(15,0)"],
  #     ["number", "(5,0)"], ["char", 3], ["number", "(15,2)"], ["char", 17]]:each>

h.merge(h) { |*,v| [v].concat(enum.next) }
  #=> {"col1"=>["123456", "char", 6], "col2"=>["0000111", "number", "(7,0)"],
  #    "col3"=>["000000002345", "number", "(15,0)"], "col4"=>["00023", "number", "(5,0)"],
  #    "col5"=>["abc", "char", 3], "col6"=>["00000000000052367", "number", "(15,2)"],
  #    "col7"=>["0000000000321456", "char", 17]}
```

This uses the form of [Hash#merge](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Hash.html#method-i-merge) that employs a block to determine the values of keys that are present in both hashes being merged, which here is all the keys of the hash.

Comment: Please don't answer questions by people who haven't shown evidence that they tried first. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, it's a repository of knowledge that more than one person will need.

Comment: @QPaysTaxes. While I understand your perspective, and know that it is shared my many SO members, I respectfully disagree, mainly because answers are not just for the asker, they are for everyone who reads the question and answers. I tend to answer when the question is interesting and/or I think I can offer an answer that will have general educational value.

Comment: Post an answer on [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/) explaining that, then. I can see what you're trying to do, but answering poorly researched questions isn't the best way to do it -- self-answers exist specifically so you can make a "teachable moment" with a generic question that isn't tied to any specific problem or requirements, but lets you demonstrate and explain a specific solution to a class of problems.

Comment: Thanks Cary that was very helpful. Infact I am getting the above result as exactly as its shown in your example.

Comment: @Cary Thanks much Cary that was very helpful. Infact I am getting the above result as exactly as its shown in your example. 
enum = arr1.zip(arr2).to_enum.

However, for the merge syntax(h.merge(h) { |*,v| [v].concat(enum.next) }), I am getting a different result. Basically it returns me Hash array of 3 elements
Array(0) - Hash of all 7 elements
Array(1) - 'CHAR'
Array(2) - 6.

Comment: TGR, I don't find a problem. Note that, after running the code, whenever you re-run `h.merge(h)...`, you must first execute `enum = arr1.zip(arr2).to_enum` (or `enum.rewind`), as all elements of `enum` will have been generated. That doesn't seem like your problem, however, and it doesn't seem like a Ruby version issue. Please recheck and if you have the same problem please show what you get in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Array#zip](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.3/Array.html#method-i-zip) to mix the hash and arrays :

```
hash = {
  key1: :value1,
  key2: :value2,
  key3: :value3
}

array1 = %i(x1 x2 x3)
array2 = %i(y1 y2 y3)

new_hash = {}
hash.to_a.zip(array1, array2).each do |(key, value), element1, element2|
  # logic with key, value, element1, and element2
  # basic example :
  new_hash[key] = [value, element1, element2]
end

p new_hash
# {:key1=>[:value1, :x1, :y1], :key2=>[:value2, :x2, :y2], :key3=>[:value3, :x3, :y3]}
```

Comment: Please don't answer questions by people who haven't shown evidence that they tried first. Stack Overflow isn't a code-writing service, it's a repository of knowledge that more than one person will need.